# Python: how to change email sender's name?

Tags: python, smtp, gmail

The emails which are sent automatically using smtplib via gmail, once are received. Receivers see the sender of the email is my email address. Is there any way to display the sender as a name that i can customize?

Answer (score 5):

If someone comes around looking for a simpler if maybe not so comprehensive, way I managed to do this very simply on yagmail v0.10.212 with:

```
yagmail.SMTP({"user@gmail.com": "Alias"}, "pwd").send(mail, subject, body)
```

I had it setup to only need the user part of the email address, but I have to use the full address when adding the dict for the alias.

If you are using a .yagmail file then you don't need the password argument as well which improves security. Or have it on a keyring, which is what i do.

`yagmail.SMTP({"user@gmail.com": "Alias"}).send(mail, subject, body)`

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this using `yagmail` (its point is to make sending emails very simple):

```
from yagmail import Connect
yag = Connect({'myemail@gmail.com' : 'SecretAliasName'}, 'pass')
yag.send('target@email.com', 'MySubject', 'You will never guess..')
```

Note that similarly, you can alias the target as well:

```
yag.send({'target@email.com' : 'Mom'})
```

You'll have to `pip install yagmail` first probably.

Comment: At time of writing this comment, the newest version of yagmail is 0.9.179, and it seem it doesn't have a `Connect` method any more, as it is replaced by SMTP. However, by using the same approach, sending mail silently fails... Do you have any idea how to do the same thing with yagmail now?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the examples and tutorials on the web can be a bit confusing as they use the username for the SMTP as the sender's name. Below is my simple Python/Gmail SMTP script. There you will see that after the "From" header of my message I can insert any string I want, which will show up in the sender line of the received email.

```
def send_email(sendName, user, pwd, recpient, subject, body):
    import smtplib
    reciever = recpient if type(recpient) is list else [recpient]
    message = "From: " + sendName + "\nTo: " + (", ".join(reciever)) + "\nSubject: " + subject + "\n\n" + body + "\n"
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(user, pwd)
        server.sendmail(user, reciever, message)
        server.close()
        print("Message Send: Success.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Message Send: Failure.")
        print(e)

send_email(input("Sender Name: "), input("Gmail: "), input("Password: "), input("Recipient: "), input("Subject: "), input("Body: "))
```